# Mopub ads only show when in Debug mode

Tags: android, twitter-fabric, mopub

I've added Mopub to my Android project via Fabric.

I get the full screen interstitial ads to show when running the app in debug mode, but when I run it regularly or via a release build they do not show.

Why could this be happening? Could it be related to proguard?